# How can block-matrices be irreducible?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix, stochastic-matrices

Suppose we define two matrices P1 and P2 as follows:

- both are 2x2 matrices
- both have strictly positive entries

And then we define P to be a 4x4 transition matrix of the form

P = 
[P1  0]
[0  P2]

It's clear here that we have two communicating classes, i.e. states 1 and 2 communicate, and states 3 and 4 communicate, however there is no communication going on between these two groups. This would imply that this matrix is **not** irreducible, and therefore does not have a limiting distribution.

I know that my understanding here is incorrect because I know that P actually does have a limiting distribution, but I'm not sure how this can be the case given that we know P to have multiple communicating classes.

Answer (score 1):

> This would imply that this matrix is **not** irreducible, and therefore does not have a limiting distribution.

Well, it does have *a* limiting distribution, but not a *unique* limiting distribution:

Let $\pi_1\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be such that $\pi_1 P_1=\pi_1$ (Or $P_1\pi_1=\pi_1$ I always forget what you want in this context) and $\pi_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be such that $\pi_2 P_2=\pi_2$, then $\lambda\pi_1\times0+(1-\lambda)0\times\pi_2$ is *a* limiting distribution of your process $P_1\times P_2$ for any $\lambda\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Could we say that it does not have a unique **stationary** distribution?

Comment: I believe any Markov process (and any aperiodic Markov chain) that has a stationary distribution has this distribution as limiting distribution in some sense. Similarly, in this case when you start in some distribution and let time go to infinity, I believe you end up in one of the found stationary distributions.